# How to make v8 generate a log file?

Tags: v8, chromium

I have compiled chromium with the command `make chrome BUILDTYPE=Release`.
Now I wish to make v8 generate a log file, I have found [this](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/V8Profiler#Command_Line) page that suggest

```
out/ia32.release/d8 --prof script.js
```

I have a folder "Release" in my out folder, but in that folder I don't have a folder named "ia32.release" or "d8".

What should I do ? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`d8` is a stand-alone V8 debugging shell. Since you built Chromium, presumably you want to profile your application running in Chromium. In this case, you don't need `d8` as you can simply use `--js-flags` command-line option as documented in [Profiling Chromium With V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/ProfilingChromiumWithV8) and [Run Chromium with flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags).